# Iterate over the same array from 2 different directions

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this problem from school:

You get a list of **N** students and a list of grades for each student. Every student gets coins. A student which has bigger grade than his neighbours from list earns more coins than them. Find the coins which every student must recieve.

Input:

```
6
Ionel
Mihai
Elena
Maria
George
Irina
9
10
8
6
9
10
```

Output:

```
Ionel 1
Mihai 3
Elena 2
Maria 1
George 2
Irina 3
```

Here is my code:

```
static void Main()
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] studentsList = FillTheList(number);
            int[] studentsGrades = ConvertList(FillTheList(number));
            PrintResult(studentsList, CalculateCoins(studentsGrades, number));
        }

        static string[] FillTheList(int number)
        {
            string[] result = new string[number];
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return result;
        }

        static int[] ConvertList(string[] array)
        {
            int[] result = new int[array.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static int[] GiveEachStudentCoins(int number)
        {
            int[] result = new int[number];
            result[0] = 1;

            return result;
        }

        static void CheckArray(int[] array, int[] theResult, int number, int counter)
        {
            int i = number;
            int count = counter;
            int[] result = theResult;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (array[i] < array[j])
                {
                    result[j] += count;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static int[] CalculateCoins(int[] array, int number)
        {
            int[] result = GiveEachStudentCoins(number);
            const int count = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                if (array[i - 1] < array[i])
                {
                    result[i] += result[i - 1] + count;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[i] += count;
                    CheckArray(array, result, i, count);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void PrintResult(string[] array, int[] array2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] += " " + array2[i];
            }

            foreach (string student in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
        }
```

It works for ascending and descending order of grades, and also for equal grades. But it doesn't work for mixed order. Here is the result I get:

```
Ionel 3
Mihai 4
Elena 2
Maria 1
George 2
Irina 3
```

My problem is on the CheckArray method I think, and I don't know how to change the logic for this thing to work.

Answer (score 0):

We can access the neighboring elements while walking through the array in a `for` loop by subtracting or adding `1` to the index of the current item. Of course before we do this, we have to make sure that the neighbor we want to check actually exists (if `i == 0` then we can't access index `i - 1`, and if `i == array.Length - 1`, then we can't access index `i + 1`).

Given this knowledge, we can follow a simple formula, just as if we were doing it "by hand" on a piece of paper:

1. Start all values in the `coins` array with `1`
2. Loop through each item in the `input` array.
3. If there's an item to the left and it's smaller than this item, then set the corresponding `coins` item to be one more than the `coins` item to it's left
4. If there's an item to the right and it's smaller than this item, and if the corresponding `coins` item is equal to the `coins` item to its right, then increment this item by `1`
5. If we incremented this item after comparing to the right, then we need to re-check the item to the left and increment it if necessary (based on the corresponding values in the `items` array).

If that didn't make complete sense, try it on paper and it may be more obvious. Otherwise, hopefully this code sample will help:

```
public static int[] GetCoins(int[] input)
{
    int[] coins = new int[input.Length];

    // Initialize coins array with all '1's (similar to 'GiveEachStudentCoins')
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.Length; i++)
    {
        coins[i] = 1;
    }

    // Examine the neighbors of each item in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // Check left neighbor (if there is one)
        if (i > 0 && (input[i] > input[i - 1]))
        {
            if (coins[i] <= coins[i - 1])
            {
                coins[i] = coins[i - 1] + 1;
            }
        }

        // Check right neighbor (if there is one)
        if (i < input.Length - 1 && input[i] > input[i + 1])
        {
            if (coins[i] == coins[i + 1])
            {
                coins[i]++;

                // Recheck left since we incremented this one
                if (i > 0 && input[i - 1] > input[i])
                {
                    coins[i - 1]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return coins;
}
```

---

Here's some sample code that can be used for testing, so you don't have to manually enter numbers into the console each time (this requires adding `using System.Linq` to the top of the file):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Populate the grades you want to test here
    int[] studentsGrades = {9, 10, 8, 6, 9, 10};

    // Student names are automatically generated
    string[] studentsList = Enumerable.Range(1, studentsGrades.Length)
            .Select(i => $"Student #{i} grade: {studentsGrades[i - 1]}\tcoins: ")
            .ToArray();

    // Call the new method to get the coins array
    int[] coins = GetCoins(studentsGrades);
    
    // Show the results
    PrintResult(studentsList, coins);

    Console.WriteLine("Done! Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I'm not home yet, but this works for all cases? Ascending grades, descending grades, equal grades and mixed order?

Comment: It should work no matter what order the items are in, as it just compares the direct left and right neighbors for each item when setting the value. Feel free to test it and let me know if there's some input that doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: I will when I get home. Thank you

Comment: This will get you 99.99% there.  This only does ONE pass.  When you increment the coins to the left/right it's possible that you'll need to "cascade" further down than the line to the positions further away that you already visited.  With that in mind, you could put the `for` loop inside a `while` loop.  Each time you enter the `while` loop reset a flag to false.  When ever you increase coins, change the flag to true.  The `while` loop will simply keep doing passes as long as that flag is true.